# Are these two expresions all the same:"CTest cTest(t);" "CTest cTest=t;" in C++? Only different in efficiency?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++17, move-semantics

As the subject, the related code is listed below.You could check it on https://godbolt.org/z/bcf8js.

There is no doubt that `EntityId_t c_SEDSubscribe(ENTITYID_SEDP_BUILTIN_PUBLICATIONS_READER);` calls `the user defined constructor EntityId_t(int id)` whereas I think `EntityId_t c_SEDPPubWriter = ENTITYID_SEDP_BUILTIN_PUBLICATIONS_WRITER`; should call the user defined constructor `EntityId_t(int id)` and movement assignment operator, but it's not this case since the terminate output.
In another word, I think ENTITYID_SEDP_BUILTIN_PUBLICATIONS_WRITER calls the user defined constructor EntityId_t(int id) to produce a temporary object.Since it's a rvalue(temporary object), complier then calls the movement assigment operation.Where am i wrong? I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

```
    #include<string.h>
    #include<iostream>

    #define ENTITYID_UNKNOWN 0x00000000
    #define ENTITYID_SEDP_BUILTIN_PUBLICATIONS_WRITER  0x000003c2
    #define ENTITYID_SEDP_BUILTIN_PUBLICATIONS_READER  0x000003c1

    struct EntityId_t
    {
        static constexpr unsigned int size = 4;
        char value[size];
        //! Default constructor. Uknown entity.
        EntityId_t(){
            *this = ENTITYID_UNKNOWN;
        }

        EntityId_t(int id)
        {
            int* aux = (int*)(value);
            *aux = id;
             std::cout << "EntityId_t(int id) constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        /*!
         * @brief Copy constructor
         */
        EntityId_t(
                const EntityId_t& id)
        {
            memcpy(value, id.value, size);
            std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        EntityId_t& operator =(
                const EntityId_t& id)
        {
            memcpy(value, id.value, size);
            std::cout << "copy operator() constructor" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }

        /*!
         * @brief Move constructor
         */
        EntityId_t(
                EntityId_t&& id)
        {
            memmove(value, id.value, size);
            std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        EntityId_t& operator =(
                EntityId_t&& id)
        {
            memmove(value, id.value, size);
            std::cout << "move operator(EntityId_t&&)" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }
    };



    int main()
    {
        EntityId_t c_SEDPPubWriter = ENTITYID_SEDP_BUILTIN_PUBLICATIONS_WRITER;
        std::cout << "==============================" << std::endl;

        EntityId_t c_SEDSubscribe(ENTITYID_SEDP_BUILTIN_PUBLICATIONS_READER);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClassName var{foo};
```

This directly calls the constructor, passing in `foo`.

```
ClassName var = foo;
```

This attempts implicit conversion of `foo` to `ClassName`, and *requires* that such a mechanism be available.  This could be a non-explicit conversion constructor on `ClassName` or a non-explicit `operator ClassName` on `foo`'s type.  If no such implicit conversion can be found, this is a compile-time error.

If a conversion can be found:

- Before C++17: this will create a temporary and then move-construct `var` from it if possible, or copy-construct if move-construction is not possible.  Pretty much all compilers will elide the move/copy, but such a constructor is still required to exist and be callable.
- C++17 and later: this is effectively identical to the explicit initialization form. No move/copy constructor is required to be available.

We can prove this with a simple test case:

```
class Example {
public:
    Example(int) {}

    Example(Example const &) = delete;
    Example(Example &&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    Example b = 0;
    (void)b; // Just silencing the unused variable warning
}
```

Compiling in C++14 mode yields:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:17: error: use of deleted function 'Example::Example(Example&&)'
   10 |     Example b = 0;
      |                 ^
```

Compiling in C++17 mode succeeds, indicating that no copy- or move-construction is attempted.

Note that the results are the same when the conversion happens because of an `operator Example()` present on the source value's type.

Comment: I had been confused for a long time; you have made it clear to me now.I am very grateful to you. Quote:"This attempts implicit conversion of `foo` to `ClassName`, and requires that such a mechanism be available.This could be a non-explicit conversion constructor on `ClassName` or a non-explicit `operator ClassName` on foo's type.".Is there any sequence to do this?You see, there are many kinds of ctors(copy ctor, movement ctor, copy assignment operator, movement assignment operator).

Comment: @John Here we are only speaking of implicit conversion, not copy/move construction. cppreference has [an article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) describing how implicit conversion happens.

Comment: Thank you.One more question, I completely understand the differences between `memmove(3)` and `memcpy(3)`.I wonder that why use `memmove(3)` in movement ctor whereas `memcpy(3)` is used in copy ctor in my example code.The code snippet is quoted from a wellknown open source project, so I don't doubt the correctness of it.I thought over and over, but i can't get the idea.I would be grateful to have some help on this question.

Comment: @John -- the choice of `memmove` and `memcpy` that you describe seems to be based on a pun: use `memmove` to move, and `memcpy` to copy. That's nonsense. A copy constructor and a move constructor are always used to create a new object at a different memory location (absent totally perverse code), so there's no need to worry about overlapping ranges. `memcpy` is okay here; no need for `memmove`. Even better, though, is `std::copy`.

Comment: @John To further explain what Pete is saying, `memmove()` can transfer the contents of memory between a source range and a destination range that overlap. `memcpy()` cannot handle this case but is simpler because it doesn't have to consider it. So, if you are confident that the source and destination don't overlap then use `memcpy()`; if they might overlap then use `memmove()`. Two C++ objects never overlap so `memcpy()` is appropriate here.

Comment: @PeteBecker & Pete Becker Thank you a lot. **If i understand you correctly** , two C++ objects never overlap (and `memcpy` is appropriate here) because  the array used in the `struct EntityId_t` is a local variable, each object would allocate an array in stack when the object is being constructing.Am i right?

Comment: @John -- yes, that's it. Although it's true for **all** `struct EntityId_t` object, not **just** local variables. The array is inside the object, and objects never overlap.

Comment: @John To be clear, one C++ object can exist inside another. This happens normally when you declare an `std::string` member of your class, for example -- the string object lives in the object of your class. Placement-new can be used to create objects within a `char` array. (This is how `std::vector` works.) However, that's not happening in this case.

Comment: @cdhowie Thank you very much. **I understand each sentence in your comments.** But for the latter part of your comments(quote:"Placement-new can be used to create objects within a char array. This is how std::vector works. However, that's not happening in this case. "), I don't your purpose to say so.Do you intend to tell me to pay attention to the objects which called placement-new? Their movement ctor and copy ctor need to be considered to avoid the memory overlap.Could i think in that way?

Comment: @John It's tricky. Objects in C++ cannot _partially_ overlap, but it is possible for one to be wholly contained in another. I was just giving examples of situations where this is the case. When you are copying between different array objects, you can always use `memcpy()` because if `memmove()` were necessary then that would mean the arrays overlap, and different arrays cannot overlap in C++ without undefined behavior having been invoked at some point -- and then your program is already doomed.

Comment: @cdhowie Quote:"different arrays cannot overlap in C++ **without undefined behavior having been invoked at some point -- and then your program is already doomed** [emphasis mine ]". Sorry. I am not a native speaker of English. I can't fully understand what you mean. Could you please explain that in simpler words?

Comment: @John You can think of object storage like a big tree. You have branches and leaves -- some objects can contain other objects, but they _fully_ contain them. You don't have two C++ arrays where the end of one array overlaps with the start of another, unless you have already done something wrong. Usually `memmove()` is used to move values around _within one array._

Answer (score 0):

I post the answer which has been deleted by somebody quickly.But i think it's right.

> should call the user defined constructor EntityId_t(int id) and
>   movement assignment operator

In concept, the constructor EntityId_t(int id) is called to construct a temporary object, 
which is used to initialize the object; 
in this case the move constructor would be used but not move assignment operator.

Because of copy elision, the last step (move constructor calling) 
might be omitted then both two ways get same effect: 
the object is initialized by the constructor EntityId_t(int id) directly. 
Since C++17 copy elision is mandatory, before C++17 copy elision is an optimization, even the move constructor is not called, it still must be usable.